# Deploying all project dependencies to remote maven repository

Tags: maven, deployment, nexus

I have SpringBoot project and configured a GIT pipeline to pull the dependencies from a remote Nexus repository. Many of the latest libraries are not in the remote repository. So, the pipeline downloads jars from central repository every time and taking long time to complete. How can all the project dependencies be deployed to Nexus? Do I need to create the deploy command for each of the library and execute one-by-one or is there a way to deploy all the dependencies of a project to a remote repository using a plugin with a single command? Besides, if this deploy option be failsafe and continue deploying other jars as some of the jars may be available in Nexus and is in release version so updating those libraries is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for the capabilities of a normal Nexus proxy repository. Your build should be pointing at the proxy repository, which in turn is configured to point to central. When your build requests dependencies from Nexus, they will be cached there, and served up. From that point on, Nexus shouldn't be reaching out to the remote to download anything under normal circumstances.

You don't need to manually deploy your dependencies anywhere, just pull them through the proxy.

The typical configuration for this involves a group repository. The artifacts you produce within your organization go into the hosted repository, and any third-party dependencies are pulled through the proxy. A group provides a single URL for your build to read from and for production deployment pulls.

[image: Typical CI/Nexus Configuration]